# What IIS or network config is necessary to be able to use a network alias from the host server?

Tags: iis

Our web server hosts some APIs that other apps running on the same server need to call. These calls are failing with a 401.1 error.

The server has a single IP address. The server name and the network alias we use both ping to this same address.

I can browse to addresses on the server from other computers using either the machine name or the alias.

If I connect to the server I can't browse to any addresses using the alias. The machine name works locally but not the alias.

If I use the alias I am prompted to to login with my credentials. These are not accepted and then leads to 401.1 error.

How can I configure the server and/or IIS to allow the network alias to be browsed from the same server that the alias links to?

Comment: The callers of any web API should send proper credentials to avoid 401.1. If your case, the web browser prompts, it is possible that you forget to add the alias to the proper security zone, so that the browser does not send your credentials by default, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password

Comment: are you using any authentication in iis? if you yes then which authentication you are using?